# How to delete rows from column which have matching values in the list Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am finding outliers from a column and storing them in a list. Now i want to delete all the values which
are present in my list from the column.
How can achieve this ?

This is my function for finding outliers

```
outlier=[]

def detect_outliers(data):

    threshold=3
    m = np.mean(data)
    st = np.std(data)

    for i in data:
        #calculating z-score value
        z_score=(i-m)/st
        #if the z_score value is greater than threshold value than its a outlier
        if np.abs(z_score)>threshold:
            outlier.append(i)
    return outlier

This is my column in data frame

df_train_11.AMT_INCOME_TOTAL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))

outlier_list=[]
def detect_outliers(data):
    threshold=0.5
    for i in data:
    #calculating z-score value
        z_score=(df.loc[:,i]- np.mean(df.loc[:,i])) /np.std(df.loc[:,i])
        outliers = np.abs(z_score)>threshold

        outlier_list.append(df.index[outliers].tolist())
    return outlier_list

outlier_list = detect_outliers(df)

[[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 8],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8],
 [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]]
```

This way, you get the outliers of each column. `outlier_list[0]` gives you `[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]` which means that the rows 1,2,etc are outliers for column 0.

EDIT

Shorter answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
df[((df.B - df.B.mean()) / df.B.std()).abs() < 3]
```

This willfilter the DataFrame where only ONE column (e.g. 'B') is within three standard deviations.

Comment: how can i  remove outliers ?

Comment: see my edited answer. also you need to choose one column based on which, you will detect the outliers